# Dual booting Windows 7/Ubuntu and partitioning on a 220GB SSD / 1TB HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I am not a technical user and am not familiar with any of these linux/unix/ubuntu terms - I'm looking for an easy to follow, non-technical guide for setting up my system - please tell it to me like I'm a fifth grader.

I currently have an Asus G75VX equipped with a 250gb SSD and a 1TB HDD.

My OS right now is Windows 7, and I'm looking to dual boot with Ubuntu so that all of my important applications/files are located on the SSD and the more long-term storage files are located on the HDD.

Comment: Post this to see used partitions. Many Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary or a few newer Windows 7 used UEFI. sudo parted -l from a terminal in the live installer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Installer can handle this situation pretty easily. When installing select `Install along Windows 7` and set the partition of Ubuntu to (ideally) 40GB. Make sure you select the SSD HDD disk as the installation disk (usually `sda`, but it may vary across machines).

Comment: When I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 I can't use the Install along Windows 7 option, it just says "This computer currently has no detected operating systems." I think this might have to do with the fact that my Windows 7 installation is located on my SSD.

Comment: Try booting Ubuntu in "Live Mode" and open a Terminal prompt. Then type `fdisk -l` to see if the drive is detected by Linux. Finally edit your original post and append that info. Thanks!